# calculate length of linestring (geo) in databricks

Tags: pyspark, line, databricks, geo

We import a dataset with a geo-column. This geo-column represent a line. When I import the data into a dataframe the data in the geo-column looks like this:

LINESTRING (155337.4045392797 368804.3359240878, 155355.9229438164 368779.3184124769, 155373.0222553128 368756.2129847418, 155388.3646412735 368731.7390974509, 155407.6144665894 368681.0098514915, 155420.4474846997 368647.1914807712, 155436.6551315848 368622.2950623668, 155457.1933884901 368596.075214043, 155466.4756062801 368586.0079242395, 155491.8449842462 368569.6328123881)

The datatype of this column in the dataframe is string.
I need to calculate the length. How do I do this.

I tried several things with geopandas and with shapely, but I cannot get it to work. somehow I don't seem to understand the syntax or I am forgetting stuff

To check if the data in the geocolumn is valid geo-data, we wrote the dataframe to a table where the geo-column was datatype geometry. and from that tabel we can calculate the length. Sot it is valid data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

together with a co-worker I solved the issue

we need these libraries:

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from shapely import geos, wkb, wkt
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas as gpd
```

then we import the data as a dataframe and convert the dataframe to a pandas dataframe

```
df_basis = spark.sql(sql_basis)
df_pandas = df_basis.toPandas()
```

geometry column as variable (optional)

```
column = 'geometrie'
```

read geometry column as wkt

```
df_pandas[column] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df_pandas[column])
```

add column 'lengte' to geopandas dataframe (lengte is Dutch for length)

```
df_pandas['lengte'] = gpd.GeoSeries(df_pandas['geometrie']).length
```

[image: screenshot]
That's it